# How can I make a responsive 45 degree image overlay in css

Tags: css

I actually have no idea how to css overlay a full width slideshow like that (picture attached). I've tried a lot of ideas with transform and rotate, but failed on responsive views. Thanks for any hint&help!

[image: css overlay]

Comment: You need to give more context - what environment are you working in? What software are you using? etc. Some code would also help...

Comment: <div id="slider"><img src="picture.jpg"></div>  just as simple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with gradient. Just ajust the gradient for your image ratio.

```css
.image {
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
}

.image img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width:100%;
}

.image:after {
  position:absolute;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: linear-gradient(33.5deg, rgba(255, 50, 54, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 26, 28, 0.5) 49.9%, rgba(255, 25, 27, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `linear-gradient` and you got it:

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,rgba(255,0,0,0.8) 50.5%),
   url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069) center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

And with a simple image:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
}
.box img {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8) 50.5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/200?image=1069">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Temani Afif, it's a slideshow, can't work with backgrounds as images are loaded into the slides.

Comment: @Dublay this solution is responsive unlike the other one ;)